# apache poi - reading comments from blank and missing (null) cells

Tags: java, null, comments, apache-poi, cell

I'm trying to read comments from all Excel documents cell's (using Apache POI).
I have problem when empty (or missing) cells contains comments.

Currently only solutions that I found is to:

- iterate every row to last not empty column
- get all (even empty) cells
- check if cell's comment is not empty
- if true: handle comment

Some code:

```
if (row != null) {
  cell = row.getCell(cellNum, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
  cellComment = cell.getCellComment();
  if (cellComment != null)
    ...
}
```

Main problems is that I can't read comments from empty lines and comments which are after last not empty cell.
Increasing performance (comparing to reading all row cells) would be nice, but main point is to read ALL documents comments.

Comment: I find POI to be unusable and poorly documented.  I'd recommend Andy Khan's JExcel as a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the comments of Blank Cell or Null cell using missingCellPolicy, `row.getCell(int cellnum, MissingCellPolicy policy)` which allows you to deal with the cells which are blank or null.

For example in your sheet, say the 7th row is blank and its 5th col have some comment (say "Hello"), and you need to read that comment. just do the following:

```
 Comment comment = sheet.getRow(7).getCell(5, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).getCellComment();

 System.out.println(comment.getString());
```

will print "Hello".

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer but my problem is that I'm reading many of files and I don't know where or even if at all there are any comments in single file.

Answer (score 0):

To all martyrs who are using Apache POI and trying to do what OP want: use sheet.getCellComments() method - it retuns a TreeMap which keys are CellAddress'es and values are Comment instances, even if cells that handle them are null or missing.

To make that kind of cells visible for POI iterators, simply ask getCell method with MissingRowPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK.

e.g. (for Java 1.8+):

```
sheet.getCellComments().forEach((cellAddress, o) ->
             sheet.getRow(cellAddress.getRow()).getCell(cellAddress.getColumn()
                        , Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK));
```